# Fedora.x86_64 - D Language - Eclipse DDT - Adding user Libraries

Tags: plugins, dependency-injection, d, fedora

Alright, so I've been racking my mind on how to include a library, Derelict(2), in the eclipse plugin, DDT or Descent, and I can't for the life of me get it. I'm missing something BIG.

I've made sure everythings been placed and unpacked the right way:
- Installed DMD compiler
- Installed and Configured DDT to its default (druntime/import and phobos)
- YUM installed derelict2, causing the .di files to be available in the dmd folder

I've tried everything from manual downloads and makes with lib pragmas to altering the buildpath to include the derelict .di files. All have failed.

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to specify the library search path. So, say your libraries you want to use are in `/home/duser/lib`, then your DMD command line should contain `-L-L/home/duser/lib` to instruct DMD compiler where to look for those libraries. I do not know where in the DDT you specify library search paths... The same thing is with the third-party D sources, or D interface files - you need to specify the include search path as well (similar to C/C++ header files) with the -I flag...

Comment: That's all and good, and for a regular non-plugin project, that would be the answer with out a doubt, but sadly it's not as simple as editing a build command.

I need a way in which the plugin will allow me to either edit the build file (apparently impossible) or include it as an external libraries like the JDT does, mainly because eclipse plugins only seem to allow you those two options of external library/.di inclusion. Both allude me.